# StoryBoard completly disappeared, i.e the VIEWCONTROLLER is totally blacked

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, viewcontroller

[As shown in the below Image, the ViewController got totally Blacked and the cause is still unknown. Even to fix the warnings I need to have a look at the elements present on the screen but sadly they aren't visible. This has happened multiple times and it's very much irritating that every time i need to force Quit the Xcode app and Re-Launch it.
Kindly please do suggest some tips to avoid or even write down some quick fixes.]
**Note: There are no code ERRORS**
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OkHI.png)

Force-Quitting and Re-launching seems to be working but not for a long time, like the application quits by itslef (CRASHES). Additionally, sometimes Xcode won't even launch and to fix this I need to RE-Start my whole System (M1-MACBOOK AIR 8GB-RAM and 256 GB ).
**NOTE:There's no storage issue and also the primary memory has enough space to run the Xcode.**

Comment: the swiftUI tag is wrong. it should be deleted.

Comment: in the picture you attached, in the bottom of that is an icon that has red color, the icon has "appearance" feature, could you press that and check it? I think your application appearance is Dark.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall Xcode again, Maybe that will solve your problem.

Comment: I tried quit and reopen sir, It worked. But do you think that's a BUG?